# What's the word for someone who consistently replies to positive statements in a contrarian manner?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage

An example of this would be,

"I like [x]."

And, unprompted, the other party replies,

"I don't like [x], I think [y] about it and that's what makes it bad."

They persist to find reasons to malign or belittle whatever it is that's positive. The contrarian aspect is what's stumping me, otherwise, I'd just say contrarian. If this or naysayer are accurate enough, let me know! I just didn't know if they had the right nuance.

Comment: Hello and welcome. You mention that the contrarian aspect is stumping you, but being contrary seems to be exactly the behaviour you’re seeking a word to describe. Please [edit] your question to explain why it stumps you. For example, do you want to exclude the mirrored case where the other party supports a position precisely because you speak against it?

Comment: A *smellfungus*, perhaps.

Comment: There are lots of words for argumentative/contrarian, and for negative/pessimistic/eeyorish, and general terms like malignant/poisonous/hostile. Or if it was someone who tells you all the bands you like are terrible, they might be a music snob or an elitist. Not sure you'll get better than naysayer or contrarian but there may be some obscure slang.

Comment: From the duplicate: argumentative; contentious; controversial[ist]; gainsayer; quarrelsome; cantankerous; antagonist[ic]; contrarian; disputatious ...